# Firefox and Edge won't upload more than one image

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have created a test page in order to revamp my fileManager class. My problem is that neither Firefox nor Edge are uploading more than one image. If I select more than one image nothing is being passed. No $_POST,no $_FILES, nothing. Here is my simple HTML and the begining script of my fileManager class I'm testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Restricted</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="file" multiple name="lFront[]" placeholder="Left Front">
<input type="file" multiple name="rFront[]" placeholder="Right Front">
<input type="file" multiple name="lRear[]" placeholder="Left Rear">
<input type="file" multiple name="rRear[]" placeholder="Right Rear">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>`
<?php
include_once('includes/fileManager.php');
include_once('config.php');
$root = dirname(__FILE__).'\\';

if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
$file = new fileManager($root.'clientImages\\', 'testfolder' , "testfolder1");

$file->uploadFile($_FILES['rFront']);
$file->uploadFile($_FILES['lFront']);
$file->uploadFile($_FILES['rRear']);
$file->uploadFile($_FILES['lRear']);
}
var_dump($_POST); // This outputs nothing after for submission if I have more than one image trying to upload

?>`
```

This is my uplodFile function and the var_dump is always empty if more than one image is uploaded

```
public function uploadFile($file, $webp = NULL) {
    echo 'In uploadFile<br>';
    var_dump($file);

if ( !is_array($file) ) return false;
    // To store all of the image names
    $stringName = array();
     }
```

I would appreciate any help or advice

I have looked up why the response was being truncated. went into firefox's about:config and changed devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit to 0. That did not render any results. This is a straight html issue. I have no idea why they won't upload

Comment: have you verified in the browser's Network tool that it isn't sending all the files? To be sure it's not a problem on the PHP side?

Comment: Have you tried a general `var_dump($_FILES);` to examine the whole upload content, in case that gives any clues.

Comment: Have you tested in any other browsers (e.g. Chrome, Opera etc) to confirm this is just specific to only these two browsers you mention? It wasn't clear in the question whether you'd explicitly ruled out other browsers, or simply hadn't tested them.

Comment: You are probably running into one of the POST request size related limits here, with the amount of data you are uploading. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size: _"If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, **the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.**"_

Comment: The largest file/image I'm uploading is 7.9Mb the smalles is 6.55 Mb. The post_max_size sounds like it may be the issue. I'll have to look into my php.ini file to see what it is set at. Basically what I'm doing is when I take a picture with my phone, I'm uploading those images to a site I use to track my clients so the pictures are usually 4032x3024 dims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBroe was correct. Thank you. It was a php.ini issue

> You are probably running into one of the POST request size related
> limits here, with the amount of data you are uploading.
> php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size: "If the size of post
> data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES
> superglobals are empty."

- CBroe
  7 hours ago